# How to access the instance in OpenStack, configure external network

Tags: ssh, installation, instance, openstack

I have installed OpenStack on a Centos 7 vm using PackStack, I have created the network configuration, an internal and an external network both interconnected by a router, but I have the problem that I cannot access the instance and it does not return the ping, I already configured the pair of keys and the security group, at the time of creating the external network I did it this way:

Name: External_Network

Project: LAB

Provider Network Type: Flat

Physical Network: **ens163**

This physical network must be the problem because **ens163 is the name of my network interface** of the vm Centos where the installation of Openstack lies ... I think the problem is in the part of linking the physical network, how can I map the interface physics to a logical segment?

Answer (score 0):

There is simple dictionary in neutron configuration, called bridge_mappings, that map between the bridge and the physical network that represent it.

For finding the interface that connected to the bridge, its depend of the network plugin

For ovs, just type `ovs-ofctl show {bridge name}`

For linux bridge, run `brctl show`